# Why do i get infinite type error

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement my own concat using folds and stumbling here. Why do i get "cannot create infinite types" error?

```
merge2 xs  = foldl conc ([]) xs
             where conc x y = (x : y)
```

Comment: The type of foldl is `(b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, the type of conc (which is just `(:)`) is `c -> [c] -> [c]`. The type checker determines that `b ~ c` and `b ~ [c]`, which implies that `c ~ [c]`, which is an infinite type and not allowed in haskell. You probably wanted `foldl (flip (:)) []`, which is just `reverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the type of x and y in the expression `x : y` - the type of `y` must be a list of whatever type `x` is, due to the definition of `:`. If you try to follow the types of `foldl`, in particular the type of its accumulator function, you will end up needing a list of lists of lists of...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could trick GHCi into showing you the types of interim expressions. First, your original definition,

```
f xs = foldl conc [] xs where conc x y = (x : y)
```

gives you an error about *"infinite type" "a = [a]"*. Now, replace `conc` in `foldl` with something else:

```
f xs = foldl g [] xs where conc x y = (x : y) ; g = g
```

No type errors there! If you still have errors replace every identifier used in some expression with `g2 = g2`, `g3 = g3` etc. Such definitions are equivalent to defining `g = undefined`, whose use will cause an error, but more importantly for us its type is free to become anything, as needed.

Now the trick is to define it as some simple value, say a Boolean:

```
f xs = foldl g [] xs where conc x y = (x : y) ; g = True
```

this gives us an error about type mismatch between *"a -> b -> a"* and *"Bool"*. We know `True` has type `Bool`, so we conclude that `g` must be of type `a -> b -> a`. We could find this out directly as well, with `:t` command:

```
Prelude> :t foldl
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
         -------------
```

Continuing, we can now compare `conc` with some simple value:

```
f xs = foldl g [] xs where conc x y = (x : y) ; g = g ; h = conc == True
```

Again we get type mismatch error between *"a -> [a] -> [a]"* and *"Bool"*. `True :: Bool` (has type `Bool`), so `conc :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. And originally we used it where now `g` is, so their types must match:

```
g    :: a -> b   -> a
conc :: a -> [a] -> [a]
                   ------
                   a ~ [a]
```

which is impossible.

Comment: Nice answer. Much better than mine!